# Merge two dataframe columns into one column with a second column containing their labels

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns, tidyr

This may be similar to the pivot function but I'm not sure if it applies in this case:

If I have a df:

```r
  date x1 x2
1 1-01 a  b 
2 1-01 c  d
3 1-02 e  f
4 1-02 g  h
5 1-03 i  j
```

Can I combine the `x1` and `x2` column into this:

```r
   date  combined type
1  1-01  a        x1 
2  1-01  b        x2
3  1-01  c        x1 
4  1-01  d        x2
5  1-02  e        x1
6  1-02  f        x2
7  1-02  g        x1
8  1-02  h        x2
9  1-03  i        x1
10 1-03  j        x2
```

I tried using `paste` (e.g. `df <- paste(df$x1,df$x2)`) but I lose out on the labels. I'm not sure if I can incorporate the `pivot_longer` function into a mutate statement in my ggplot statement.

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_longer(quux, -date, names_to="type", values_to="combined")` and `reshape2::melt(quux, id.vars="date", variable.name="type", value.name="combined")`